# Import error : cannot import name 'open_filename' from 'pdfminer.utils'

Tags: python, pdfminer

On importing `pdfminer.high_level`, I am getting an error cannot import name `open_filename` from `pdfminer.utils`.

I tried following steps:

1. `pip3 install pdfminer.six`
2. `import pdfminer`
3. `import pdfminer.high_level`

(and encountered error on this line)

---

```py
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-772e4980255d> in <module>
----> 1 import pdfminer.high_level

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\high_level.py in <module>
     12 from .pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
     13 from .pdfpage import PDFPage
---> 14 from .utils import open_filename
     15 
     16 

ImportError: cannot import name 'open_filename' from 'pdfminer.utils'
```

Comment: I also faced this issue (python `3.9` and `3.6`), what I did was to install `pdfminer.six` with python `3.8` and it worked

Answer (score 27):

Hi I had the same issue.

I had installed both `pdfminer` and `pdfminer.six`. Please keep `pdfminer.six` and uninstall `pdfminer` with:

```
pip uninstall pdfminer
```

Answer (score 3):

First Uninstall the pdfminer.six

> > pip3 uninstall pdfminer.six

Then re install

> > pip3 install pdfminer.six

It has solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem: `cannot import name 'open_filename' from 'pdfminer.utils'` when using the [langchain cookbook](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/master/cookbook/Semi_structured_multi_modal_RAG_LLaMA2.ipynb?ref=blog.langchain.dev).
Problem was python v.3.11x.
I downgraded my env to 3.8.18 and it worked.

Comment: Just for reference for others, I was also facing this error which using langchain pdfuploader with Python3.8 and above solution worked. Uninstall pdfminer and install or keep pdfminer.six.

Answer (score 0):

I had an older version of pdfminer.six. This is the [commit](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six/commit/1a4a06da9fe295920e23311e12f22a37a2799899) that introduced the `open_filename` method. Make sure your pdfminer.six version is greater than '20200402'.